# The letter combination " ' " + " t " triggers Spyder to run

Tags: python, ide, spyder

So, this is a rather exotic problem, but it's been driving me crazy and I don't know when to look. If I want to type plain text in English, the combination `'t` (e.g. in the word "can't") triggers Spyder to run. No other combination does the same thing. Turning my keyboard from English International to some other setting fixes the problem; however, I'd rather not resort to that.

Comment: @Ali Same problem. It has nothing to do with the place where I type " 't ". Just typing it is what triggers it.

Comment: I think you should include a question in your Question, like "How do I turn if off?" or "How do I remap to something else?" or what it is what you expect from an Answer.